# how to segregate the column wrt certain conditions in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

i have a dataframe df as shown below:

```
VehNum  Control_circuit control_circuit_status  partnumbers     errors     Flag
4234456 DOC             ok                      A567UR      Software Issue  0
4234456 DOC             not_okay                A568UR      Software Issue  1
4234456 DOC             not_okay                A569UR      Hardware issue  2
4234457 ACR             ok                      A234TY      Hardware issue  0
4234457 ACR             ok                      A235TY      Hardware issue  0
4234457 ACR             ok                      A234TY      Hardware issue  0
4234487 QWR             ok                      A276TY      Hardware issue  0
4234487 QWR             not_okay                A872UR      Hardware issue  1
3423448 QWR             not_okay                A872UR      Hardware issue  1
```

i want to add a new column called "Control_Flag" and perform below operations: for each VehNum ,Control_circuit if it has flag value only 0 then Control_Flag column will hold value 0 else if it has 0 ,1 or 2 then Control_Flag column will hold value 1.

result should be as below:

```
VehNum  Control_circuit control_circuit_status  partnumbers     errors     Flag Control_Flag
4234456 DOC             ok                      A567UR      Software Issue  0   1
4234456 DOC             not_okay                A568UR      Software Issue  1   1
4234456 DOC             not_okay                A569UR      Hardware issue  2   1
4234457 ACR             ok                      A234TY      Hardware issue  0   0
4234457 ACR             ok                      A235TY      Hardware issue  0   0
4234457 ACR             ok                      A234TY      Hardware issue  0   0
4234487 QWR             ok                      A276TY      Hardware issue  0   1
4234487 QWR             not_okay                A872UR      Hardware issue  1   1
3423448 QWR             not_okay                A872UR      Hardware issue  1   1
```

how to achieve this using pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a aggregate window with SUM() will help achieve this

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("4234456", "DOC", "ok", "A567UR", "Software Issue", 0),
        ("4234456", "DOC", "not_okay", "A568UR", "Software Issue", 1),
        ("4234456", "DOC", "not_okay", "A569UR", "Hardware Issue", 2),        
        ("4234457", "ACR", "ok", "A234TY", "Hardware Issue", 0),
        ("4234457", "ACR", "ok", "A234TY", "Hardware Issue", 0),
        ("4234457", "ACR", "ok", "A234TY", "Hardware Issue", 0),        
        ("4234487", "QWR", "ok", "A276TY", "Hardware Issue", 0),
        ("4234487", "QWR", "not_okay", "A872UR", "Hardware Issue", 1),
        ("3423448", "QWR", "not_okay", "A872UR", "Hardware Issue", 1),
    ],
    ["VehNum", "Control_circuit", "control_circuit_status", "partnumbers", "errors", "Flag"],
)

df_agg_window = Window.partitionBy(
    "VehNum",
    "Control_circuit",
)

df = (
    df
    .withColumn(
        "flag_sum",
        F.sum("Flag").over(df_agg_window),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "Control_Flag",
        F.when(
            F.lower(F.col("flag_sum")) > 0,
            F.lit(1),
        )
        .otherwise(F.lit(0)),
    )
    #.drop(F.col("flag_sum"))
)


df.show()
```

output:

```
+-------+---------------+----------------------+-----------+--------------+----+--------+------------+
| VehNum|Control_circuit|control_circuit_status|partnumbers|        errors|Flag|flag_sum|Control_Flag|
+-------+---------------+----------------------+-----------+--------------+----+--------+------------+
|4234457|            ACR|                    ok|     A234TY|Hardware Issue|   0|       0|           0|
|4234457|            ACR|                    ok|     A234TY|Hardware Issue|   0|       0|           0|
|4234457|            ACR|                    ok|     A234TY|Hardware Issue|   0|       0|           0|
|4234487|            QWR|              not_okay|     A872UR|Hardware Issue|   1|       1|           1|
|4234487|            QWR|                    ok|     A276TY|Hardware Issue|   0|       1|           1|
|4234456|            DOC|                    ok|     A567UR|Software Issue|   0|       3|           1|
|4234456|            DOC|              not_okay|     A569UR|Hardware Issue|   2|       3|           1|
|4234456|            DOC|              not_okay|     A568UR|Software Issue|   1|       3|           1|
|3423448|            QWR|              not_okay|     A872UR|Hardware Issue|   1|       1|           1|
+-------+---------------+----------------------+-----------+--------------+----+--------+------------+
```

Comment: can u help me with this also:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74527853/how-to-segregate-the-column-wrt-ok-and-notok-conditions-in-pyspark-dataframe-col

Comment: @karthik sure once you mark this solution as accepted answer

Comment: have accepted the answer, thanks for your help.   can  you help me with this similar use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74527853/how-to-segregate-the-column-wrt-ok-and-notok-conditions-in-pyspark-dataframe-col