# How to segregate the column with respect to OK and not OK conditions in pyspark dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a *dataframe* `df` as shown below:

```
VehNum  Control_circuit control_circuit_status  partnumbers     errors     Flag
4234456 DOC             ok                      A567UR      Software Issue  0
4234456 DOC             not_okay                A568UR      Software Issue  1
4234456 DOC             not_okay                A569UR      Hardware issue  2
4234457 ACR             ok                      A234TY      Hardware issue  0
4234457 ACR             ok                      A235TY      Hardware issue  0
4234457 ACR             ok                      A234TY      Hardware issue  0
4234487 QWR             ok                      A276TY      Hardware issue  0
4234487 QWR             not_okay                A872UR      Hardware issue  1
3423448 QWR             not_okay                A872UR      Hardware issue  1
```

I want to add a new column called `"Control_Flag"` and perform the below operations: for each `VehNum`, `Control_circuit` if it has `"control_circuit_status"` has the status "ok" in that `Control_circuit`  then `"Control_Flag"` value will be `0` else `1`.

The result should be as below:

```
VehNum  Control_circuit control_circuit_status  partnumbers     errors     Flag Control_Flag
4234456 DOC             ok                      A567UR      Software Issue  0   0
4234456 DOC             not_okay                A568UR      Software Issue  1   0
4234456 DOC             not_okay                A569UR      Hardware issue  2   0
4234457 ACR             ok                      A234TY      Hardware issue  0   0
4234457 ACR             ok                      A235TY      Hardware issue  0   0
4234457 ACR             ok                      A234TY      Hardware issue  0   0
4234487 QWR             ok                      A276TY      Hardware issue  0   1
4234487 QWR             not_okay                A872UR      Hardware issue  1   1
3423448 QWR             not_okay                A872UR      Hardware issue  1   1
```

How to achieve this using pyspark?

Comment: @iambdot , can u help me with this use case

Comment: your output is incorrect you not_okay set for all QWR values..this doesn't match your input

Comment: yeah like if distinct vehicle,distinct  Control_circuit has atleast 1 ok status then Control_Flag value will be 0 for those Control_circuit else if it has only Not_okay status then Control_Flag  value will be 1.how to achieve this

Comment: sorry , got ur question edited it now

Comment: VehNum 4234487 should have Control_Flag value 0..since theres an ok and not_okay records right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the solution

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("4234456", "DOC", "ok", "A567UR", "Software Issue", 0),
        ("4234456", "DOC", "not_okay", "A568UR", "Software Issue", 1),
        ("4234456", "DOC", "not_okay", "A569UR", "Hardware Issue", 2),        
        ("4234457", "ACR", "ok", "A234TY", "Hardware Issue", 0),
        ("4234457", "ACR", "ok", "A234TY", "Hardware Issue", 0),
        ("4234457", "ACR", "ok", "A234TY", "Hardware Issue", 0),        
        ("4234487", "QWR", "ok", "A276TY", "Hardware Issue", 0),
        ("4234487", "QWR", "not_okay", "A872UR", "Hardware Issue", 1),
        ("3423448", "QWR", "not_okay", "A872UR", "Hardware Issue", 1),
    ],
    ["VehNum", "Control_circuit", "control_circuit_status", "partnumbers", "errors", "Flag"],
)

df_agg_window = Window.partitionBy(
    "VehNum",
    "Control_circuit",
)

df = (
    df
    .withColumn(
        "cc_status",
        F.when(
            F.lower(F.col("control_circuit_status")) == "ok",
            F.lit(1),
        )
        .when(
            F.lower(F.col("control_circuit_status")) == "not_okay",
            F.lit(0),
        )
        .otherwise(F.lit(0)),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "flag_sum",
        F.sum("cc_status").over(df_agg_window),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "Control_Flag",
        F.when(
            F.lower(F.col("flag_sum")) > 0,
            F.lit(0),
        )
        .otherwise(F.lit(1)),
    )
    .drop("cc_status", "flag_sum")
)


df.show()
```

output:

```
+-------+---------------+----------------------+-----------+--------------+----+------------+
| VehNum|Control_circuit|control_circuit_status|partnumbers|        errors|Flag|Control_Flag|
+-------+---------------+----------------------+-----------+--------------+----+------------+
|4234457|            ACR|                    ok|     A234TY|Hardware Issue|   0|           0|
|4234457|            ACR|                    ok|     A234TY|Hardware Issue|   0|           0|
|4234457|            ACR|                    ok|     A234TY|Hardware Issue|   0|           0|
|4234487|            QWR|              not_okay|     A872UR|Hardware Issue|   1|           0|
|4234487|            QWR|                    ok|     A276TY|Hardware Issue|   0|           0|
|4234456|            DOC|                    ok|     A567UR|Software Issue|   0|           0|
|4234456|            DOC|              not_okay|     A569UR|Hardware Issue|   2|           0|
|4234456|            DOC|              not_okay|     A568UR|Software Issue|   1|           0|
|3423448|            QWR|              not_okay|     A872UR|Hardware Issue|   1|           1|
+-------+---------------+----------------------+-----------+--------------+----+------------+
```

Comment: i have similar use case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74530527/how-to-concate-two-columns-according-to-conditions-in-pyspark-dataframe